# masking of email address in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to mask email address with "*" but I am bad at regex.

```
input : nileshxyzae@gmail.com
output : nil********@gmail.com
```

My code is

```
String maskedEmail = email.replaceAll("(?<=.{3}).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");
```

but its giving me output `nil*******e@gmail.com` I am not getting whats getting wrong here. Why last character is not converted?
Also can someone explain meaning all these regex

Comment: Is this your real email address? If so, you might want to consider changing it...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your look-ahead `(?=[^@]*?.@)` requires at least 1 character to be there in front of `@` (see the dot before `@`).

If you remove it, you will get all the expected symbols replaced:

```
(?<=.{3}).(?=[^@]*?@)
```

Here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ2jV5/1) (replace with `*`).

However, the regex is not a proper regex for the task. You need a regex that will match each character after the first 3 characters up to the first `@`:

```
(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\G)[^@]
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ2jV5/4), replace with `$1*`. Here, `[^@]` matches any character that is not `@`, so we do not match addresses like `abc@example.com`. Only those emails will be masked that have 4+ characters in the username part.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/xH4ijS):

```
String s = "nileshkemse@gmail.com";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]", "$1*"));
```

Comment: Second regex can be simplified to `(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\G)[^@]`

Comment: @nhahtdh: Or `(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\G)[^@](?=[^@]*@)`. What is interesting here is that after removing the look-ahead the number of steps to complete the match increases.

Comment: You need to check the checkbox "Disable internal engine optimization" in the debugger. After you do so, they have the same number of steps for the failing case, and the one without look-ahead has less steps in the success cases. In Java, there is no optimization for the case with look-ahead.

Comment: Thank you for reminding about the hint on how to use regex101 for debugging Java regex better :) Perhaps, a possessive quantifier can be used to overcome that drawback, but I agree removing it is a valid way to proceed here.

Comment: I want to skip the one character before `@` and i am using `(?<=.{3}).(?=[^@]*?@)` regex. So the output of `mianabdulmateen@gmail.com` should be `mia***********n@gmail.com`.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: @MateenChaudhry Use `(?<=.{3}).(?=[^@]+@)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s5XaWl/1).

Comment: I use s.replaceAll("(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]", "$1*").replaceFirst("[*]+", "***") to get nil***@gmail.com because I want to mask the char count as well

Comment: @MUHMobileInc. I doubt you need that complex solution then. Use `s.replaceFirst("^([^@]{3})[^@]+", "$1***")`

Comment: Need help in here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75783919/email-masking-using-regex

Answer (score 19):

If you're bad at regular expressions, don't use them :) I don't know if you've ever heard the quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   "I know, I'll use regular expressions."   Now they have two problems.

([source](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski))

You might get a working regular expression here, but will you understand it today? tomorrow? in six months' time? And will your colleagues?

An easy alternative is using a `StringBuilder`, and I'd argue that it's a lot more straightforward to understand what is going on here:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(email);
for (int i = 3; i < sb.length() && sb.charAt(i) != '@'; ++i) {
  sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
}
email = sb.toString();
```

"Starting at the third character, replace the characters with a `*` until you reach the end of the string or `@`."

(You don't even need to use `StringBuilder`: you could simply manipulate the elements of `email.toCharArray()`, then construct a new string at the end).

Of course, this doesn't work correctly for email addresses where the local part is shorter than 3 characters - it would actually then mask the domain.

Answer (score 10):

Your Look-ahead is kind of complicated. Try this code :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String s = "nileshkemse@gmail.com";
    s= s.replaceAll("(?<=.{3}).(?=.*@)", "*");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P :

```
nil********@gmail.com
```

Comment: Why `\w` instead of simply `.`? This leads to "foo.bar@gmail.com" -> "foo*bar@gmail.com" instead of "foo****@gmail.com".

Comment: @xehpuk - Ya. Hadn't thought about that scenario. Changed my code now.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
//In Kotlin

val email = "nileshkemse@gmail.com"
val maskedEmail = email.replace(Regex("(?<=.{3}).(?=.*@)"), "*")
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.In java we have replaceAll but in kotlin we do not have.It is posted for kotlin learning user.

Answer (score 3):

I like this one because I just want to hide 4 characters, it also dynamically decrease the hidden chars to 2 if the email address is too short:

```
public static String maskEmailAddress(final String email) {
    final String mask = "*****";
    final int at = email.indexOf("@");
    if (at > 2) {
        final int maskLen = Math.min(Math.max(at / 2, 2), 4);
        final int start = (at - maskLen) / 2;
        return email.substring(0, start) + mask.substring(0, maskLen) + email.substring(start + maskLen);
    }
    return email;
}
```

Sample outputs:

```
my.email@gmail.com    >    my****il@gmail.com
info@mail.com         >    i**o@mail.com
```

Comment: how to mask the gmail too? with the same way

Comment: @VanyaRachel - Did you find out how to do that ?

Comment: You can make a function out of the the if block and use it this time with: domain = email.substring(0, at + 1) and `at` as length of domain. I haven't added to the answer because I want to keep it simple and short.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static string GetMaskedEmail(string emailAddress)
    {
        string _emailToMask = emailAddress;
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress))
            {
                var _splitEmail = emailAddress.Split(Char.Parse("@"));
                var _user = _splitEmail[0];
                var _domain = _splitEmail[1];

                if (_user.Length > 3)
                {
                    var _maskedUser = _user.Substring(0, 3) + new String(Char.Parse("*"), _user.Length - 3);
                    _emailToMask = _maskedUser + "@" + _domain;
                }
                else
                {
                    _emailToMask = new String(Char.Parse("*"), _user.Length) + "@" + _domain;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return _emailToMask;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Extension**

```
/**
 * Format email id in the following format
 * (m••••••n@gmail.com)
 * only exception for 2 character username in that case it will be ••@gmail.com
 * @return formatted email
 */
fun String.maskEmailId(): String {
    return if (this.isNotNullOrEmpty() && this.indexOf('@') > 0) {
        val index = this.indexOf('@')
        val maskedUsername = if (index > 2) {
            "${this.substring(0, 1)}${"*".repeat(index-2)}${this.substring(index-1)}"
        } else {
            "*".repeat(index) + this.substring(index)
        }
        maskedUsername
    }  else ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will try to mask even if the character count before the `@` is less than or equal to 3.

```java
    public static String maskEmail(String fieldValue) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(fieldValue)) {
            return "";
        }
        int pos = fieldValue.indexOf('@');
        if (pos == -1) {
            return "*".repeat(fieldValue.length());
        }
        int chars = Math.min(pos-1, 3);
        String pattstr = "(^[^@]{%d}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]".formatted(chars);
        return fieldValue.replaceAll(pattstr, "$1*");
    }
```