# Replace String with characters with substring

Tags: java, android

I tried to make security to display email data by replacing some words with symbol (*) but not as expected there might be an error in making the example script as below.

```
String email = "thismyemail@myhost.com";
String get_text = email.get_text(3, 6);
String hasil = email.replace(get_text,"*");
email_string = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailT);
email_string.setText(hasil);
```

But the result is like this

```
thi*email@myhost.com
```

Which I expect

```
thi***email@myhost.com
```

Comment: simplist would be `String hasil = email.replace(get_text,"***");`

Comment: `email.get_text(3, 6);` I guess you mean substring?

Answer (score 3):

```
String hasil = email.replace(get_text,"***");
```

But please note that if that text appears anywhere else in the string it will be replaced as well.

Also, if the email is like `jf@mymailserver.com` you won't be replacing a part of their user id with `*`.

So you can probably find a better way to select the characters, taking into account email length and also not "replacing" text but rather putting those chars at the specific position you want to.

See this related question for some ideas on how to improve this:

[masking of email address in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100298/masking-of-email-address-in-java)

Comment: not at all, just pointing to the solution in his particular implementation, but then I added more content to the answer to point some issues

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems right. If ur expected output is like the one mentioned above, you can just add 2 more "*" to the code.

```
String hasil = email.replace(get_text,"***");
```

I hope it helps