# Email masking using regex

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, regexp-replace

I have to mask my email, that is, to replace a few letters with asterisks.

**Here is my requirement**

1. Input — `asxyz@ifyourock.com`

   Output —  `**xyz@ify**********`
2. Input — `xyz@gmail.com`

   Output — `xyz@gma******`
3. Input — `asxyz.abc@gmail.com`

   Output —  `******abc@gma******`
4. Input — `car@domain.com`

   Output — `car@dom*******`
5. Input — `as@domain.com`

   Output — `as@dom*******`

Here is my regex which I tried:

```kotlin
fun maskEmail(email: String): String {
    val regex = "(.{3})(.*)(@.{3})(.*)".toRegex()
    return regex.replace(email) { matchResult ->
        val (prefix, middle, atSymbol, domain) = matchResult.destructured
        "${prefix}${"*".repeat(middle.length)}${atSymbol}${"*".repeat(domain.length - 2)}"
    }
}
```

But it's giving a wrong output as:

Input — `asxyz@ifyourock.com`

Output — `as***@ify**********`

I have to retain **<=3** letters before and after `@`

I need help to achieve above outputs.

Comment: I have edited my question as asterisk was not coming in start so i wrote 2star and 6 star for example

Comment: The output shown for examples (1) and (3) is very confusing.

Comment: @AdrianHHH asterisk was not coming on editor so i wrote as 2 star/asterisk and 6 star/asterisk there before letters

Comment: Please check that the changes I made are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know much about Kotlin, but playing around in an online IDE, I came up with:

```
fun main() {    
    var lst = arrayOf("asxyz@ifyourock.com", "xyz@gmail.com", "asxyz.abc@gmail.com", "car@domain.com", "as@domain.com")    
    lst.map{println(it.replace("[^@](?!.{0,2}@|(?<=@...)|(?<=@..)|(?<=@.))".toRegex(), "*"))}
}
```

Try this [online](https://pl.kotl.in/1uhK37XqK)

---

**EDIT:**

I tried to find a way to be more dynamic in your search pattern. The above would require you to have each option of length to be their own respective alternative in the pattern. So to avoid this, I pieced together:

```
fun main() {
    var lst = arrayOf("asxyz@ifyourock.com", "xyz@gmail.com", "asxyz.abc@gmail.com", "car@domain.com", "as@domain.com")
    lst.map{
        val m = ".{0,3}@.{0,3}".toRegex().find(it)!!
        println("*".repeat(it.length).replaceRange(m.range.first , m.range.last, m.value))
    }
}
```

Try this [online](https://pl.kotl.in/ppe3T5f9B)

---

Or, without regex:

```
fun main() {
    var lst = arrayOf("asxyz@ifyourock.com", "xyz@gmail.com", "asxyz.abc@gmail.com", "car@domain.com", "as@domain.com")
    lst.map {
        val i = it.indexOf("@")
        println(((0..it.length-1).map{x -> if (x<i-3||x>i+3) "*" else it[x]}).joinToString(""))
    }
}
```

Try this [online](https://pl.kotl.in/7PWdv6_YB)

---

All options print:

```
**xyz@ify**********
xyz@gma******
******abc@gma******
car@dom*******
as@dom*******
```

Comment: worked but giving warning in compiler as Unnecessary non-capturing group '(?:.{0,2}@|(?<=@...)|(?<=@..)|(?<=@.))'

Comment: Yeah, I suppose `[^@](?!.{0,2}@|(?<=@...)|(?<=@..)|(?<=@.))` does work too.

Comment: @IRONMAN, thanks for the feedback, I did try to find a way to avoid having to be so explicit in the regex pattern. I had to puzzle a bit since I'm unfamiliar with Kotlin. Hope the update helps.